# Attemping to install Ubuntu alongside Windows (dual-boot) on my Dell XPS 13 9370

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell, xps

I am aware of a number of related questions and solutions but I am at the point of trying them all without any success.

Recently, I have upgraded SSD in my Dell XPS 13  and was hoping to go for dual-boot setup. I started with installing Windows 10 - there were some problems, it wasn't detecting the new SSD.

Somewhere I've read that I should change the SATA operation in BIOS from RAID ON to AHCI. I did that and installed Windows without any other problems. I shrunk the Windows partition and left 50GB of unallocated space. Then I downloaded Ubuntu, made a bootable USB with `Rufus` and tried to install it.

Here is my problem in a nutshell. I  cannot install Ubuntu from USB - Ubuntu starts off the USB but when I'm trying to install, it's not detecting my SSD.

The solution that helps some people is to change from `RAID ON` to `AHCI` but I had already done that. Also I checked `Windows Device Manager` the storage controllers and it is in fact what it's supposed to be (according to this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1127531/1006012).

I did also all sort of related things in BIOS - enabling usb boot, disabling secure boot, changed Fastboot to Thorough, etc.. I have also disabled Fastboot in Windows Power Options and made sure it is not hibernating - that seems to lock the drive somehow.

Also I tried using different ports for my USB adapter(all are USB-C but 2 of them are also Thunderbolt3).

If anybody has an idea how can I fix that, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have found the solution. You can just read https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408864&page=2 but I will write exactly what I did:

- Press `F12` and choose to boot from USB.
- Press `e` when the options try ubuntu and install appear.
- At the end of the line starting with `linux` add `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200`. I've also deleted the `---` that was after `quiet splash`. Not sure if that's necessary.
- Press `CTR + x` - that will boot into Ubuntu.
- Choose option to install, it should detect the SSD now.
- Install alongside Windows (Windows partition was shrunk previously).
- Now when you restart it will let you choose ubuntu/windows but ubuntu won't boot. The previous fix was just temporary. We need to save this line in grub. Before turning off ubuntu go to grub file `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and after `quitet splash` add `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200`. Save file and run `sudo update-grub`.

After that it works perfectly fine. It lets me choose if I want to boot into Ubuntu or Windows.